# Pandas: grouping values by date-time index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                     Values
Date_Time

2016-01-04 12:00:00  778000
2016-01-04 18:00:00  35
2016-02-04 04:00:00  45
2016-02-04 11:00:00  47
2016-03-04 07:00:00  51
```

I want to count how many occurrences I have for each day:

```
                    Occurrences
Date_Time

2016-01-04           2
2016-02-04           2
2016-03-04           1
```

And I am trying to achieve it by doing:
`df2=df.groupby.index.count_values()`, but the result is not what I wish it was. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't want to group by a datetime though, it looks like you want to group by date only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, there are 2 possible solutions - convert `DatetimeIndex` to `dates` by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) - then is necessary converting to `Series` or remove `time`s by [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) - get `DatetimeIndex` again:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index.date).value_counts()
print (s)
2016-01-04    2
2016-02-04    2
2016-03-04    1
dtype: int64

print (s.index)
Index([2016-01-04, 2016-02-04, 2016-03-04], dtype='object')

print (type(s.index[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

---

```
s = df.index.floor('d').value_counts()
print (s)
2016-01-04    2
2016-02-04    2
2016-03-04    1
dtype: int64

print (s.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-02-04', '2016-01-04', '2016-03-04'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Last is possible create one column `DataFrame` with set index names use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
s = df.index.floor('d').value_counts().to_frame('Occurrences').rename_axis('Date_Time')
print (s)
            Occurrences
Date_Time              
2016-02-04            2
2016-01-04            2
2016-03-04            1
```